# Cakephp Facebook Connect using Nick Baker's plugin : Error=> FB Dosen't exist

Tags: cakephp, facebook, facebook-graph-api, cakephp-1.3

I am working on Nick Baker's CakePHP Facebook plugin. I am doing exactly as he has described in his screencast http://tv.cakephp.org/video/webtechnick/2011/01/12/nick_baker_--_facebook_integration_with_cakephp

But when I am trying to get the currently logged in user **$this->Connect->user()** using the *Facebook.Connect* component, i do not get any return value.....

When I debug the current session, (**debug($this->Session);**), i get the following :

app/app_controller.php (line 10)

SessionComponent Object
(

```
[__active] => 1
[__bare] => 0
[valid] => 
[error] => Array
    (
        [2] => FB doesn't exist
    )

[_userAgent] => 36267ef3c9f36ab07ac8e68d1deb03aa
[path] => /sharefaredev
[lastError] => 2
[security] => medium
[time] => 1301436341
[sessionTime] => 1301448341
[cookieLifeTime] => 720000
[watchKeys] => Array
    (
    )

[id] => 
[host] => localhost
[timeout] => 
[enabled] => 1
```

)

Where does the error come from? I'm not able to make that out.

Please help!
Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked facebook's app settings to ensure that App Settongs > Website > Core Settings reflect your current working site?

Comment: Well somehow changing the app settings worked ..... I dont sure know which ones though ....

Comment: I'm glad it did. Let us know what you changes you made,once you could figure out, so that we could have a better understanding of it.

Comment: Basically I changed my app domain to the web (not local) and it worked.